# Store not working properly after modification refresh Opencart v3

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

Store was working fine. I was creating a module and had to refresh. I went to admin > modification and click on trash and refresh button. after that my store messed up and now its not working. Admin panel is working perfectly fine. I tried to clear cache and refresh again but nothing is working. I kept caching disabled for development reasons.

i'm using opencart version 3 and this theme [ThemeDemo](http://demo.opencartworks.com/#so_topdeal3_layout1). This is how it looks after hitting refresh button
[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXOQ.png)

```
2018-02-10 6:34:18 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-10 6:38:08 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-10 6:39:00 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-10 6:39:59 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-10 6:39:59 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-10 6:46:29 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-10 6:46:52 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Bug Fixing OC-3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: OCMod Editor

FILE: admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php
CODE: $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/modification/refresh', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . $url, true);
LINE: 657
CODE: $data['modifications'][] = array(
LINE: 679
CODE: $data['tab_log'] = $this->language->get('tab_log');
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

FILE: admin/view/template/marketplace/modification.twig
CODE: <div class="pull-right">
LINE: 5
CODE: {% if not modification.enabled %}
LINE: 96
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Simple Blog

FILE: admin/controller/common/column_left.php
CODE: $report = array();
LINE: 728

FILE: admin/language/ar-ar/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 104

FILE: admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
CODE: $_['text_other_status']
LINE: 102
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Mobile - Opencart 3.x
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So OnePage Checkout
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Social Login
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So ThemeConfig

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: while ($action instanceof Action)
LINE: 59

FILE: admin/controller/design/layout.php
CODE: public function index()
LINE: 5
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: design/layout_form
LINE: 403
CODE: $design = array();
LINE: 352
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: So Tools
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: clear all the files in modification folder and check the store front

Comment: I went to system > storage > modification. I removed all files from this folder. Still I have the time issue.

Comment: @SharikShaikh try clearing up the `vQmod` cache as well. If you've that installed.

Comment: Rohit. I'm not using vQmod. What I did, I went to my git repo and grabbed content of modification folder ( All Folders and files ) pasted in that modification folder and everything started working normally.

Comment: @SharikShaikh are you using the `dummy` data for the theme? maybe that caused this issue. I've also used the same template but in lower version of `opencart`.

Comment: maybe you can  uninstall the theme and try to reinstall the theme, please check theme options also and opencart error log

Comment: @RohitBatra Yes I'm using dummy data provided by theme owner. But how that could cause an issue with the template?. Can you please tell me little more about that and thanks for your help.

Comment: @karthickeyan Thank you. Ill try that and get back here.

Comment: I tried fresh install and issue is not there anymore but that theme is provided by client and has to be installed. From git I took older version of site and I saw that the catalog folder and files weren't getting generated. So, I added that catalog folder from old commit and site started working fine.